# Programmatically determine if an Excel workbook (.xls) has been digitally signed

Tags: c#, vba, excel, ms-office

I currently have a management program (written in .NET 4.5) that packages up Excel workbooks for download to our customers.  The workbooks are saved as .XLS (requirement).  I'm looking for a method (either via Excel 2010 VBA or .NET 4.5 C#, preferably C#) of programmatically checking if an Excel workbook has been digitally signed.

EDIT: I was mistaken regarding the requirements.  I need to be looking for the digital signature on the VBA/Macro side of the house.

For example:
open an excel workbook
click the Developer tab, click 'Tools', click 'Digital Signature'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with Microsoft Office Tools. In the assembly `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.v4.0.Utilities` you will find that the WorkbookBase class has a `Signatures` property that returns a collection. WorkbookBase documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbookbase.aspx). In particular Signatures is defined as

> Gets the collection of digital signatures for the workbook

Since it is a collection you can iterate over it or use the `Count` property to determine how many digital signatures are present. The collection is a SignatureSet and documentation on it can be found in the documentation at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.signatureset_members.aspx). Count is defined as:

> Returns an Integer indicating the number of items in the specified collection.

You can use the regular `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly and the normal Workbook class to determine if the **VBA code** has been signed via the `VBASigned` property on a `Workbook` object. Information on that property can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.vbasigned.aspx).

> Gets a value that indicates whether the Visual Basic for Applications project for the workbook has been digitally signed.

Assuming you are using C# and the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` assembly has been added as a reference in your VS C# project then code like this would open your workbook and get the VBASigned boolean flag:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

[snip]
Excel.Application exApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook exWbk = exApp.Workbooks.Open(@"c:\path\to\your\workbook.xls");
Boolean signed = exWbk.VBASigned;

exWbk.Close();
// When finished make sure we release the Interop COM objects we used
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(exWbk);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(exApp);
```

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation.  Unfortunately I was incorrect regarding the requirements; I need the signatures applied to the VBA/Macro side.  My apologies for the mistake.

Comment: @Falconeer I have amended the answer with information on checking if the VBA code has been signed